# SOAPUI: Can I set up multiple test case responses when I don't know the order the requests will come in

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using SOAPUI to test an application.  To initiate the test, I send a JMS message to the software from SOAPUI.

There are multiple hooks in the code that are built to respond to this JMS message, including a few that respond by making web service requests to services I intend to mock with SOAPUI.  I cannot predict the order these requests will arive in.

In SOAPUI I have had success setting up tests as long as the order of the requests is predictable (since the test case essentially "waits" when a response step is present).

In my current scenario, I can't do that.  Is there any way around this?

Example:
JMS Message A
-- triggers SOAP Request for method A on Service
-- triggers SOAP Request for method B on Service

The order of these requests is unpredictable and based on other factors.

In SOAPUI, I can set a test case that does the following:
Send JMS Message A
Mock Response for method A on Service
Mock Response for method B on Service

But if B comes in first, this will not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create separate test steps for each request and feed input from step A to step B. I believe it will run sequentially